# Laravel 5 - File::makedirectory

Tags: laravel-5, mkdir

I simple just can't get this to work in Laravel 5. and furthermore Laravel doesn't give me any errors to work with. I have build a small CMS system where users are allowed to create a gallery page. When the gallery page is created it should create a folder for the user as well.

```php
$path = public_path('/userfiles/3/Galleri/1');

File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
```

I'm trying this, and tried different other approaches. I'm working in Laravel 5 and on a shared host, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: did you put `use File;` at the top?

Comment: Hi Jonju 
I have yes. I dont know if it's because of the shared hosting, that it might be adding the folder some weird place? :)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me. Give it a try

```
use File;
$path = public_path('/userfiles/3/Galleri/1');
File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
```

OR

```
$path = public_path('/userfiles/3/Galleri/1');
\File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
```

Comment: This will possible work for every one else :) but this i what i have tried this far.

Answer (score 0):

You should check it  before create directory

```
$path = public_path('/userfiles/3/Galleri/1');

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($path);
    }
```